# Интеграция Wordpress и Intellj idea

Tags: wordpress, intellij-idea

Начал разбираться в вордпрессе, открыл проект вп через II(intellj idea) и понял, что он не знает функций wp, начал гуглить как интегрировать одно в другое, наткнулся на оф документацию. Поковыряв ее пару часов - ни к чему не пришел, инфы на русском - нет, а в английском я днище...
Так вот, собственно вопрос: может ли кто-то объяснить как это делается?

Ссылка на документацию:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html

Ультимейт версия есть, не пиратка.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Для работы с WP используют PhpStorm. Он умеет всё - знает функции WP, php, обеспечивает отладку и т.д. Эта IDE от JetBrains очень похожа на IDEA по интерфейсу, но платная. Впрочем, есть возможность загрузить альфа-версию официально и бесплатно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign , а чем отличается WebStorm от PhpStorm? мне кажется ультимейт версия intellij должна включать их обе? нет?

Comment: WebStorm для html, css, js. PhpStorm в первую очередь для php, но и html, css, js тоже поддерживает. Плюс базы данных, отладка, Git, и ещё масса прочих сервисов.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо